# Scrapy yields only the last element

Tags: python, scrapy

I am scraping some courses/lessons with the help of `scrapy`, however it seems to yield only ever the **last** element of a list.
Here's the code in question:

```
def parse_course_list(self, response):
    """ Scrape list of lessons for each course """
    lessons = response.css('ul.lessons-list a')
    for lesson in lessons:
        title = lesson.xpath("text()").extract_first().strip()
        link = lesson.xpath("@href").extract_first().strip()

        url = response.urljoin(link)
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['Lesson'] = title
        item['URL'] = link

        yield scrapy.Request(url, \
            callback=self.parse_lesson,
            meta={'item': item} \
        )
```

So basically I am scraping the lessons and yield a request for the details page. However, the lesson is always the same in the `parse_lesson` function.
Am I missing something here completely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah... The classic pointer problem!

I'm not sure on why this happens besides that the requests you're yielding carry items with the same address on the stack.

Here is how you can solve it:

```
def parse_course_list(self, response):
    lessons = response.css('ul.lessons-list a')
    itemToCopy = response.meta['item']
    for lesson in lessons:
        item=itemToCopy.copy()
        ...
```

The rest is just as it is minus the `item = response.meta['item']` obviously.

Tell me how it went.

Comment: It went well, muito obrigado :) I did it in one line though: `item = reponse.meta['item'].copy()`, that's allright, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I split the declaration and assignment to be easier to understand, glad it worked out ;)